# Using SPEL to populate DTOs with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a web application with a restful endpoint /widget/{id}.

This endpoint takes an update DTO and calls out to a service layer to do the update.

I currently extract the updated data from the JSON body. However the service needs more data than the JSON body contains such as the current user, and the id from URL.

Currently my controller method looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public WidgetResponseDto update(@RequestBody WidgetUpdateDto widgetUpdate,
                                    @PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                    @CurrentOrganisationId Long organisationId)
```

and the first job of the controller is to munge this data into a single object. This pattern is then repeated across the application.

My question is: How can I take a parameter from the path, or from say the `SecurityContext` and use it directly in my DTO.

Ideally, I would like to be able to use SPEL in my business object to populate these fields along with using Jackson to populate the other fields.

Is this supported out of the box? If not would I be best off writing a custom `HttpMessageConverter`?

Answer (score 0):

You can access request headers through `@RequestHeader` annotation:

```
RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public WidgetResponseDto update(@RequestBody WidgetUpdateDto widgetUpdate,
                                @PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                @CurrentOrganisationId Long organisationId,
                                @RequestHeader("Host") String host,
                                @RequestHeader(""Keep-Alive"") String keepAlive)
```

Request headers "Host" and "Keep-Alive" will be available through `host` and `keepAlive` variables respectively.
See [API](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.htm) for more details

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt help. I want to be able to inject the path variable directly into my WidgetUpdateDto, not the controller method.

Comment: Can you show method body pls? Or the way you inject request params inWidgetUpdateDto if else?

Comment: At the moment I create a new object which has the fields from the dto aswell as the request param values and orgId munged into a single object as the first think the method does. 

new WidgetUpdate(widgetUpdate.name, widgetUpdate.type, id, organisaitonId) 

for example.

Alternatively, I could use a setter on the Dto for the same purpose.